# mysql if condition add value else add value1

Tags: mysql, if-statement, group-by, conditional-statements

I'am trying to get total full time and total half time by user, Timing is stored in single column, Integer value of timing should come in full time as sum(timing) and floating value  in half time but in count

```
id user_id timing
1   2       1
2   2       2.5
3   1       1.5
4   1       1
5   3       3
6   2       2.5
```

I need the result as

```
 user_id  fulltime halftime
   1        2         1
   2        5         2
   3        3         0
```

Comment: Did you do your homework ?

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT user_id
     , SUM(FLOOR(timing)) AS fulltime
     , SUM((timing % 1) * 2) AS halftime
  FROM table
 GROUP BY user_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

This query should help you. please try it on your data

```
SELECT  user_id, 
        sum(if(ceil(timing)>timing,0,timing)) as fulltime,
        sum(if(ceil(timing)>timing,timing,0)) as halftime 
FROM    rest 
GROUP BY user_id
```

Thanks
Amit